# Sodium percarbonate and sulfuric acid reaction

Tags: acid-base, analytical-chemistry

If an excess sulfuric acid is added to a detergent containing sodium percarbonate, would it be possible for the excess acid to react with hydrogen peroxide?

I believe that the hydrogen peroxide will be released from the reaction with sulfuric acid given by this reaction

$$\ce{2Na2CO3·3H2O2 + 3H2SO4 -> 3H2O2 + 2NaSO4 + 2CO2 + 2H2O}$$

So if an excess acid is added will it react with hydrogen peroxide to yield peroxymonosulfuric acid?

[image]