# Can someone help me finish this reaction?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, water

This question revolves around sodium percarbonate (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_percarbonate) and its reaction with sulfuric acid.

I didn't find anything, so I tried assembling it myself.

Wikipedia says that $$\ce{2Na2CO3·3H2O2 -> 2Na2CO3 + 3H2O2}$$ in water.

Now I'm not sure if the $\ce{Na2CO3}$ does this: $$\ce{Na2CO3 + H2SO4 -> Na2SO4 + H2O +CO2}$$ or this: $$\ce{Na2CO3 + 2H2SO4 -> 2NaHSO4 + H2O + CO2}$$

Last, the $\ce{H2O2}$ reacts with $\ce{H2SO4}$ to peroxymonosulfuric acid (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peroxymonosulfuric_acid) $$\ce{H2SO4 + H2O2 <=> H2SO5 + H2O}$$ in high concentrations / to a small extend.

So, my final equation could be: $$\ce{2Na2CO3·3H2O2 + 2H2SO4 -> 2Na2SO4 + 2H2O + 2CO2 + 3H2O2}$$ or $$\ce{2Na2CO3·3H2O2 + 4H2SO4 -> 4NaHSO4 + 2H2O + 2CO2 + 3H2O2}$$ or $$\ce{2Na2CO3·3H2O2 + 5H2SO4 -> 2Na2SO4 + 5H2O + 2CO2 + 3H2SO5}$$ or $$\ce{2Na2CO3·3H2O2 + 7H2SO4 -> 4NaHSO4 + 5H2O + 2CO2 + 3H2SO5}$$

Which is correct or the most correct? Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: We prefer not to use MathJax in titles, sine it looks terrible from Google.

Comment: Duplicate: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/51652/sodium-percarbonate-and-sulfuric-acid-reaction